# Assert.AreEqual(double, double) con valores calculados falla cuando son iguales

Tags: c#, comparaciones, test

Estoy tratando de realizar un test para el calculo del importe de un artículo. El problema se presenta al momento de comparar el importe calculado por el objeto responsable de esto y el calculado en el test.

Tengo lo siguiente:

```
public void TestCalculaImporteFinalConsiderandoImpuestosAsignados()
    {
        int codigoInterno = 353535;
        string codigoBarras = "1234567890123";
        string nombre = "Test artículo";
        double precioUnitario = 10.50;
        double alicuotaIVA = 21;
        double cantidadVendida = 20.32;
        double montoImpuestoInterno = 10;


        double precioUnitarioConCantidad = precioUnitario * cantidadVendida;
        double importeEsperado = precioUnitarioConCantidad + montoImpuestoInterno * cantidadVendida + precioUnitarioConCantidad * alicuotaIVA / 100;
        double importeCalculado;

        Impuesto impuestoInterno = new Impuesto(Impuesto.NOMBRE_IMPUESTO_INTERNO, montoImpuestoInterno, TipoMonto.FijoPorUnidad);
        ArticuloModelo modelo = new ArticuloModelo(codigoInterno, codigoBarras, nombre, precioUnitario, alicuotaIVA);

        modelo.ImpuestoInterno = impuestoInterno;
        importeCalculado = modelo.CalcularImporteFinal(cantidadVendida, precioUnitario);

        Assert.AreEqual(importeEsperado, importeCalculado);
    }
```

Realizando el calculo con la calculadora me da **461,3656**. El mismo valor que contienen las variables: `importeEsperado` e `importeCalculado`. Pero el test falla diciendo:

```
Assert.AreEqual failed. Expected:<461,3656>. Actual:<461,3656>.
```

Entonces mi pregunta: ¿La comparación falla porque a nivel de bits las variables son distintas?

Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Entrando en modo `debug` pude comprobar que las variables tenían los valores:

- ImporteCalculado = 461.3656
- ImporteEsperado = 461.36560000000003

Por lo tanto la comparación daba que eran números distintos. Debido a que no me afecta la diferencía de calculo, opté por cambia la forma de determinar si el test pasa aceptando un error de `0.0001`:

```
Assert.IsTrue(Math.Abs(importeCalculado - importeEsperado) < 0.0001);
```